# Sklearn MultinomialNB gives 1 probability for some class for few examples?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification, naivebayes

I used MultinomialNB from sklearn for some text data.
Data contains 12 class.
And its classification task.
After applying **MultinomialNB** with **CounterVectorizer** i checked few example's predicted class probability.And for some reasons one class shows **1.0 probability**.

> [[  3.91049692e-23  , 2.50074669e-28 ,  1.85836050e-36 ,
>         4.29028609e-37 ,  9.58721828e-35 ,  4.20270658e-38 ,
>         1.21649822e-39 ,  8.09756242e-39 , 1.09065133e-39 ,
>         1.00000000e+00 ,  7.31365410e-22 ,  1.68756182e-37]]

This are the probabilities for some example and **class 10** gives 1.0 probability. I dont know how this can be possible.
I also checked for particular feature probability in this example for class 10 (p(x/class10)wherexϵclass10). And its non-zero(ofcourse because of smoothing in MultinomialNB).

If anyone know any reason why this can be a case please share. Comment if need more info about code.

PS : Model is also predicting good amount of data correctly(73% of them). Most of the wrong prediction data have 1.0 probability class in it.

Comment: Did you figure out the solution? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: @nishantvodoo Yes. Its not a bug or something. I looked into their code and find that sklearn normalize its probability and in this above case when one of the class's probability is dominating it normalized to ~1. You can look into github code for more detailed understanding .

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will take a look at Github code. I started encountering new problem. Probability is 1 if I was TfidfVectorizer and it is fine when I use CountVectorizer. I see this behavior only in MultinomialNB. Other algorithms give sensible results. Was wondering if you ever encountered the same issue too.

Comment: @nishantvodoo I haven't look into that but I can think of one reason why it can be the case. Tfidfvectorizer and CountVectorizer both give different input to your model so it may be the case for different probability output. If both approaches giving the same priority to each class then it won't matter.